# Problem: Google Colab import libraries and authorization to use google drive takes too long?

Tags: directory, authorization, google-colaboratory, drive

I execute this part of code in google colab, to authorize me so to get access to my drive folders

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null 
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
 auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
 creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret=    
{creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id= 
{creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

But when it comes to the part of copy and paste the verification code from the given url, execution doesn't end, so to move on the next block. What is the problem?even though I am still connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I made a new effort and seems to work, in order to mount your drive to the colab-notebook use these lines instead,

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Run it,

Click on the link accept and copy-paste the given code, hit enter done! Much simpler from the previous way I've asked about which by the way it still not working.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1srw_HFWQ2SMgmWIawucXfusGzrj1_U0q) tutorial, I've been using this for the past few days, and what has worked for me is the following:

1.- In a single cell run:

`from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()`

2.- Follow the link, copy and paste the generated password

3.- In another cell run:

`from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
prompt = !google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass(prompt[0] + '\n\nEnter verification code: ')
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}`

4.- Again, follow the link, copy and paste the new generated password

5.- Proceed to mount your drive and work with your files!

Comment: Still when I copy and paste the generated password ...
 cell "currently executing.." never ends execution

Comment: It's a shot in the dark, but perhaps adblock? or browser? I use Chrome

Comment: I've also tried Chrome on linux (without any add-ons) but still the same

Comment: Sorry @TassosK, I only have my own experience and my colleagues. I hope you can find a solution!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue other folks are encountering being discussed here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/231

Do you also see any 400s or errors on the JS console?

Comment: Actually I'm one of them ...but still there is not any convincing answer

Answer (score 0):

After pasting in your generated code, hit enter on the keyboard. It will continue to buffer until you do.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).